# C# DLL exception not caught in unmanaged C++

Tags: exception, com

As part of this exercise in familiarizing myself with using C# DLLs in unmanaged C++ via COM, I am trying to see how exception handling works.  I wrote a tiny C# DLL that just contains a function that throws an exception, and a C++ function that calls that function and tries to catch the exception.

Here's the DLL, written in C# using Visual Studio 2012:

```
namespace ExceptionThrowingLib
{
    public interface IExceptionThrower
    {
        void ThrowException();
    }

    public class ExceptionThrower : IExceptionThrower
    {
        public ExceptionThrower() { }
        public void ThrowException()
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("c:/misc/exceptionthrower.txt", true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("Exception generation request received at " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            }
            throw new Exception("This is a requested exception.");
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("c:/misc/exceptionthrower.txt", true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("This should never appear in the output file.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the function that tries to use it, written in C++ using Visual Studio 2008:

```
void HandleException()
{   
    IExceptionThrowerPtr pThrower(__uuidof(ExceptionThrower));
    try
    {
        pThrower->ThrowException();
        AfxMessageBox(_T("No exception caught."));
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("I caught an exception!"));
    }
}
```

When I call this function, the "No exception caught" message appears.

I expected that the client (C++) side would be able to catch a _com_error object and process it appropriately to learn what happened, but it appears nothing is being caught.  Why not?  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use [#import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-import-directive-cpp) to generate the `_com_ptr` implementation?

If so, take care to omit the [raw_interfaces_only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/raw-interfaces-only) directive, since it suppresses the generation of error-handling wrapper functions.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I built the C# and C++ classes by blindly following [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/828736/how-to-call-a-managed-dll-from-native-visual-c-code-in-visual-studio-n), which did not explain the raw_interfaces_only directive.

Answer (score 0):

You're not really doing anything wrong, but have a wrong understanding.

The C++ code is not catching an exception because no exception is being thrown to the C++ code. The CLR/interop layer in the .NET runtime catches the exception before it is passed back. All good COM code never throws an exception from the COM method or property but returns a failure code.

What is the return code (HRESULT) from ThrowException().  It should not be S_OK but maybe E_FAIL or some other descriptive error.

Comment: The COM Interop layer transparently maps .NET exceptions to HRESULTS, which can then be intercepted by native clients, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/handling-com-interop-exceptions). The code of the OP apparently uses an [auto generated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-import-directive-cpp) implementation of `_com_ptr_t`, which in its default configuration throws a `_com_error` if the returned HRESULT indicates an error.

Comment: Nowhere did I read he is using _com_ptr_t or any autogenerated code. He simply states about _com_error which is defined in comdef.h if memory serves me correctly.

Comment: I auto-generated the interface code by setting ComVisible to true in AssemblyInfo.cs, selecting "Register for Com Interop" in the C# project build settings, and using #import on the resulting type library.